# Hyperbolic function in complex analysis integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to solve this integral for my complex analysis course however I can't seem to figure out how to get started on it. I think since there's exponentials in the function you want to maybe use a rectangular contour, and rewrite the hyperbolic function in terms of e as well but I'm really unsure.

Any help you guys can give would be great thanks!

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x/3}}{\cosh(2x)} dx$$

Comment: Your question is a specific case of a more general question on this site after the substitution $u=2x$: [Improper integral complex analysis $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax} \, dx}{\cosh(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1827986/323432)